# Filter out string by specific pattern

Tags: r, regex, filter

I have a data frame which contains 2 and 3 words.
I want to filter out some specific strings which has same pattern.

```
df <- data.frame(word = c("thin film", "film resistor", "thin film resistor", 
                          "protection material", "protection material removed",
                          "protection layer", "interconnect metal"))
>df                          
  words
1 thin film
2 film resistor
3 thin film resistor
4 protection material
5 protection material removed
6 protection layer
7 interconnect metal
```

I want to filter out strings which has repeated string pattern.

So it's what I want to get.

```
  words
1 thin film resistor
2 protection material removed
3 protection layer
4 interconnect metal
```

Comment: Can you spell out the exact logic for what gets removed? It looks like it's something like "if there are strings that share at least 2 words, keep the longest string of that set" - is that right or can you explain it better?

Comment: It is not clear why `protection layer` and `interconnect metal` are in the desired output. I think they are unique.

Comment: Marius: Yes, your explain is what I want to describe. "if there are strings that share at least 2 words, keep the longest string of that set". Because my data frame contains part repeated string. The repeated string is not useful for me. I only want to remain  the longest string in my data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `words` column of the character class:

There must be a best way to do this:

```
  data.frame(words=names(which(colSums(sapply(df[,1],grepl,df[,1]))==1)))                       
              words
 1          thin film resistor
 2 protection material removed
 3            protection layer
 4          interconnect metal
```

Hope this helps

You can also do:

```
 df$word[colSums(sapply(df[,1],grepl,df[,1]))==1]
 [1] "thin film resistor"          "protection material removed" "protection layer"           
 [4] "interconnect metal
```

or

```
 df$word[colSums(outer(df$word, df$word, stringr::str_detect)) == 1]
```

Comment: Good thinking. I m not sure this can be optimized any further. You could use `outer` but it will need a vectorized `grepl` (like `str_detect` from `stringr` package), i.e. `df$word[colSums(outer(df$word, df$word, stringr::str_detect)) == 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

While creating `data.frame` please set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Try this:

```
lst = strsplit(df$word,split = " ")

output = sapply(1:length(lst),
   function(t,dict){
       superstring=c()
       temp = sapply(dict[-t],function(u,v){
                  matches = match(x=v,table=u); 
                  if(length(which(!is.na(matches)))==length(v)){
                      return(str_c(u,collapse = " "))
                  }else{
                      return(NULL)
                  }},dict[[t]],simplify = T)
        if(length(which(sapply(temp,is.null,simplify = T)))==(length(dict)-1)){
            superstring[t]=str_c(dict[[t]],collapse = " ")
        }else{
            superstring[t]=temp[[which.max(sapply(temp,nchar,simplify = T))]]
        }          
       },lst)

unique(output)

#[1] "thin film resistor"          "protection material removed" "protection layer"            "interconnect metal"
```

Not the most optimized but should do the trick.